# iOS UITableViewStylePlain Sections and Row issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, row

I have trouble with implementing dynamic count of rows in two sections.

My codes below:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (mySearchBar.text.length > 0)
    {
        if(section == 0)
        {
            return @"Exact match(es)";
        }
        else
        {
            return @"Additional results";
        }
    }
    else 
    {

        return @"";
        NSLog (@"No sections!");
    }

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


    if (mySearchBar.text.length > 0)
    {

        NSMutableIndexSet *mindexes = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *firstSection = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *secondSection = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        NSUInteger i;

        for (i = 0; i <= [self.filteredListContent count] ; i++)
        {

        //  NSLog (@"mysearchbar text %@", mySearchBar.text);
        //  NSLog (@"self.filtered text %@", [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:i]);

            //if ([mySearchBar.text isEqualToString: [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:i]])
            //NSRange s = [mySearchBar.text rangeOfString: [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:i]];


            //if (s.location!=NSNotFound)
            //{
                //[mindexes removeAllIndexes];
                //[firstSection removeAllObjects];

                [firstSection addObjectsFromArray:[self.filteredListContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF beginswith[c] %@)", mySearchBar.text]]];



                //[firstSection addObject:[self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:i]];

                NSUInteger ind = [firstSection indexOfObject:[self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:i]];

                [mindexes addIndex:ind];

                /*
                if (section == 0)
                {
                    return [firstSection count];
                    [tableView reloadData];

                }
                 */
                [self.filteredListContent removeObjectsAtIndexes:mindexes];


            //}

            //else //if (!(mySearchBar.text == [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:i]))
            //{

                //[secondSection removeAllObjects];


                //[secondSection addObject:[self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:i]];

                //secondSection = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: firstSection];

                //[secondSection removeObjectsAtIndexes: mindexes];

            //  [self.filteredListContent removeObjectsAtIndexes:mindexes];

                /*
                if (section == 1)
                {
                    return [secondSection count];
                    [tableView reloadData];

                //return [self.filteredListContent count];
                }
                 */
            //}
        }

        if (section == 0)
        {
            return [firstSection count];
            //[tableView reloadData];

        }
        if (section == 1)
        {
            //return [secondSection count];
            return [self.filteredListContent count];
            //[tableView reloadData];

            //return [self.filteredListContent count];
        }


        NSLog (@"if return");
    }

    else // if (mySearchBar.text == nil)
    {

        //[total release];
        return [self.noWords count];
        NSLog (@"else return");
    }

     */
    //Add a return 0; at the end of your method. It's basically a failsafe, if none of the if conditions are met.
    return 0;
    NSLog (@"return 0!!!");

    //If you want to make sure one of the conditions is met, return -1; should cause the application to throw an exception and crash, which might help you track down errors.
    //return -1;

}
```

What I want to achieve, is that exact match(es) shows only matched words, and words coming after it (my arrays are strictly alphabetically ordered), show in additional results, but all I get is that it shows either same results in both sections, or it shows several results in exact matches, whereas it shows only one result (which is alike the first match in the first section) in additional results.

Sorry for messy codes, please point me in right direction, thank you.

Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1):

Because there are 2 section, so the numberOfRowsInSection will run 2 times, u should use if or switch at the beginning of numberOfRowsInSection, do different job with different section number, and that will let u get the right ans at different sections.